# A lower bound for $2\max (|x_1-x_2|,|y_2-y_1|)-\max(|x_2-x_3|,|y_3-y_2|)$.

Tags: inequality

Let $x_i, y_i>0$, $x_i,y_i\in \mathbb R$ $i=1,2,3$. Assume we have
$$2\max (|x_1-x_2|,|y_2-y_1|)-\max(|x_2-x_3|,|y_3-y_2|)$$
Can we find a lower bound for previous expression? I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: What are $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s  ?

Comment: This question is the same as finding an upper bound for $\max(|x_2-x_3|,|y_3-y_2|)-2\max (|x_1-x_2|,|y_2-y_1|)$, which is the $L^\infty$ distance from $p_2=(x_2,y_2)$ to $p_3=(x_3,y_3)$ minus twice the $L^\infty$ distance from $p_2$ to $p_1=(x_1,y_1)$. The restriction $x_i,y_i>0$ merely means we are restricted to points in the first quadrant of the plane. So for any $p_2$, put $p_1$ very close and put $p_3$ as far away as you like. To put either an upper _or_ lower bound you need more constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose : $$x_2 = x_1$$ $$y_2 = y_1$$ $$x_3 \rightarrow 0$$ $$x_2,y_2 < y_3$$ and $y_3 \rightarrow +\infty$, you'll find that your expression has no lower bound (it goes to $-\infty$).

It's been a while since I did some math though.

Comment: Sorry, $x_i,y_i$ are finite real numbers.

Comment: @Mark That doesn't invalidate the argument. You can chose $y_3$ arbitrarily large and $x_3$ arbitrarily small (but still $>0$) to get an arbitrarily small result.

Comment: Indeed. The point of using the arrow ("$\rightarrow$") is to say that $y_3$ is arbitrarily large but still finite, just like when you calculate the limit of an expression. Thus it is still a finite number, but it can go as high as you want.

Answer (score 2):

The choice $x = (1,1,1)$ and $y = (1,1,t)$ for $t > 1$ gives
$$2\max(|1-1|,|1-1|) - \max(|1-1|,|t-1|) = 0 - |t - 1| = 1-t$$
We can chose $t$ arbitrarily large (but still finite) to get a result smaller than any fixed real number. Thus no lower bound exists.